# How could I get my append() list, back in order? jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

So i have a list of divs i display'd using Jquery append. On every list i added an id, everytime i add an input field the number increases and when i delete it deletes only the number i want it to delete, but how i can get this number list back in order?? 
Like 1, 2, 3, 4(i delete 2) = 1, 3, 4, = wrong
more like 1, 2, 3, 4 (i delete 2), 1, 2, 3 etc.

**CODE:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var i = 1;
    $("#lisa").click(function(){
        i++;
        $(".voit").append('<div class="input-group rem'+i+'"><div class="input-group-addon ees">'+i+'. Koht</div><input type="text" name="voitj' + i + '" class="form-control" placeholder="Võitja auhind"/><div class="input-group-addon"><span id="'+i+'" class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus remove"></span></div></div>');
    });

    $(document).on('click', '.remove', function(){
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
    });
});
```

Here's jfiddle 
         https://jsfiddle.net/0wbzpumt/2/

And also, how can i set the maximum appended fields? Like if i don,'t want more than 5 input fields how can i do this.

Thanks in advance! :D

Comment: You need to traverse the array again and reassign the numbers.

Answer (score 0):

This is an algorithmic problem. You need to think it a bit better through.
Your code is not maintainable and has a few problems.

You're keeping shared state on a page. How are you going to keep track of this state across your pages or throughout the app? What happens when you hook a database to this frontend?

What is `.rem+id` ? You're using classes as identifier. There are other ways to do that (id's for example). Data-tag could be used as well.

You need to bundle all the logic in the same object. Then, changing markup, business logic or moving to a new frontend framework will not be as painful.
Your entries represent a domain reality. You should keep a collection of these (maybe in an array or an object). They'd have a unique identifier and a render method that produces the HTML markup. When you remove an element, you only need rerendering the changed markup.

Answer (score 0):

In your removal function, simply loop through each div that has the number you want updated and assign a value based on the loop index:

```
$(document).on('click', '.remove', function(){
var id = $(this).attr('id');
$('.rem'+id+'').remove();
$.each($('.input-group-addon.ees'), function(index, value) {
    if(index > 0) {         
        $(value).text(index);
  }
});
```

});

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0wbzpumt/5/)

Note that you could update other values as well inside this loop like your remX class number as well if you needed to.

**EDIT**
Reset the value of i to the number of inputs so that future additions show the correct ID value.

Comment: You should check what happens when i delete and add new input field :D Id is increasing :D But thanks tho.

Comment: Good point, I was a tad hasty.  I added a simple reset of the Id after each removal so that it doesn't run out of control.  The subtraction of 1 value is to account for the first text box "Event ID".